# Use yasnippets of other mode in web mode

Tags: javascript, emacs, yasnippet

I would like to make the snippets in `js-mode` available in `web-mode`.

There is no too many snippets in `web-mode`. What should I do to use javascript or HTML snippets in `web-mode`?

Answer (score 3):

Inside the snippets folder of web-mode, you can create a file called `.yas-parents` and just put the modes you want to include into web-mode, in your case, `js-mode`.

Several other modes use the same structure, for instance, most programming language modes have the prog-mode as parent (which contains generic stuff programmers use such as TODOs)

Comment: Is there a way to more finely control which snippets are loaded in web-mode? For example, there's no reason to load ERB snippets when editing a JavaScript file, but you can use web-mode for both. (Maybe this should be a separate question.)

Comment: I don't know how to do that. But as I understand `web-mode` is for files that contains several web-related languages (such as PHP, JS, etc). Why don't you use `js-mode` for files that are purely JavaScript?

Comment: @PatrickBrinich-Langlois See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48332/yasnippets-for-active-web-mode-engine.